# Is it worth it to have an meta intermediate comparison model for Django?

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and I want to know how to best structure my models.

I have a model `Computer` with fields `screen_size`, `price`, `company`, etc.., and eventually want to have a UI that is able to compare to other `Computer` instances.

So for example, if we're looking at `ComputerA`, the UI would show all other `Computer` instances and and compare the price, screen size, and company relative to `ComputerA`

Wondering if it's worth it to have an intermediate model `ComputerComparison`, that has two foreign keys that reference both the `Computer` instances I'm trying to compare?

Comment: A model is used for *storing* things. A comparison is normally someting that you determine in a view. Storing it would also result in data duplication which is rather hard to get in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A model is used for *storing* things (in a database). A comparison between two items is usually *not* worth storing. First of all this would scale quadratic: if you have 100 `Computer` objects, then there are 9'990 possible comparisons, if the number of `Computer`s doubles, then the total number of comparisons is roughly times *four*.

But probably more severe is the fact that you introduce *data duplication*. You will likely store (parts of) the same data twice or more in the database. The problem with data duplication is that it turns out that it is hard to keep these duplicates in sync. Imagine that you for example change the `price` of one of the `Computer` objects, then the `ComputerComparison` objects where that computer is referred to need to be updated as well. Although that might look as a simple task, it thus means that all creations, updates, deletions, and likely of multiple fields need to be taken into account. Keeping data synchronized, even on the same database is a hard problem, and therefore better avoided.

But anyway, you likely do not need to store comparisons at all. Normally these are done by a view. A view that for example is given two primary keys of the two items to compare:

```
def compare(request, pk1, pk2):
    c1 = get_object_or_404(Computer, pk=pk1)
    c2 = get_object_or_404(Computer, pk=pk2)
    # … compare c1 and c2 …
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'some_vars': some_vals})
```